# Redirect to a URL passed in the query string with Apache 2

Tags: apache-2.4, redirect, querystring

I'm pretty newbie in URL redirection, and I would like to create this kind of redirection: `http://example.com/?url=http://domain.test/` to `http://domain.test/`

The result I'm having so far is: `http://example.com/?url=http://domain.test/`
redirects to `http://domain.test/?url=http://domain.test/`

But I don't want the `?url=http://domain.test/` part.

The relevant part of my Apache2 virtual host is:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} url=(.*)
RewriteRule "/" "%1" [QSA,R=301,L]
```

I've searched into lot of forums but still can't find what I need.

Comment: From your title and your *Apache httpd* directives, I understand that you want to pass a URL in a *query string*. But in your examples, `url=value` is not a query string (a leading `?` is missing for it to be a query string). A URL with a valid query string would be `http://example.com/?url=value`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I've forgotten the leading ?

Answer (score 0):

You were close to the solution. You need to get rid of the original query string thanks to the [`QSD` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd) (supported in *Apache httpd* 2.4.0 and later versions).

So, to achieve your goal, you could use these *Apache httpd* directives:

```
# Tested with Apache 2.4.38
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^url=(.*)
RewriteRule ^ %1 [QSD,NE,R=301,L]
```

Interestingly, this solution supports URLs that have a query string themselves, e.g., `http://example.com/?url=http://domain.test/?lang=en`.

To deal with URLs that are passed encoded, like this: `http://example.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.test%2F%3Flang%3Den`, the simplest method is probably to process the passed URL with a tiny script of this kind:

```php
<?php
# WARNING: Add some security checks to prevent exploits like https://www.securityfocus.com/bid/55297/exploit
header('Location: '.$_GET['url']); # $_GET members are automatically passed through urldecode().
?>
```

If you choose to use this script, then the *Apache httpd* directives above become useless and must be removed.

**Last but not least**, you should be aware that this redirection methods represent a security/reputation risk as discussed [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/99749/301-redirect-script-being-abused-for-what-purpose).

Comment: As you said, I was close to the solution haha
Thank you so much Eric ! :D
And also thank you for additional information and warnings <3

Comment: Also, do you know how I can have a decoded URL if the %{QUERY_STRING} value is encoded ? :) 
For example : https://example.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2Flike-button%3Flocale%3Dfr_FR

Comment: @Beelzeko, I'm afraid this requires some scripting outside *Apache httpd* (e.g., in a PHP file).

Comment: @Beelzeko, I've extended my answer after your comment about encoded URLs.

Comment: thank you again for your precious help :) I'll try to create something with that

Comment: Hi @Beelzeko, if this or any other answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.